# Start-Process argument list includes nested quotes - still possible to do?

Tags: robocopy

After searching for answers and trying many things, nothing is working.

Goal: Run robocopy from within Powershell in order to grab the latest 30 days of files from a user's home directory, omitting specific folders because speed is important to migrate data off-hours.

Problem: I need to exclude a folder with robocopy with this argument:  /XD "application data"   However, I can't use normal quotes because the -Argumentlist of Start-Process interprets those as new arguments even without a comma.

Command line robocopy that works fine:
robocopy (source) (dest) /S /MAXAGE:30 /XD appsensedata,"application data"

Command I'm working with:
Start-Process robocopy -argumentlist "$source","$dest","/R:0","/S","/MAXAGE:30","/XD appsensedata,"application data""

To exclude \application data, Robocopy has to have quotes around the path since it has a space in it. I tried with old 8-character names like \applic~1\ but that didn't work. I also tried double quotes, apostrophe instead of quotes, backslash before each quote...nothing works. The single quotes pass to the robocopy command and don't work because it looks for a folder with the name 'application data' with the single quotes as part of the name.

I just need it to pass those quotes as part of the argument instead of translate it as part of the Start-Process command.

Alternatively, if someone knows of a way to use Copy-Item to take the most recent files recursively and copy them somewhere else recursively, recreating the folder structure. I can not get it to recreate the folder structure, but I probably could with some insanely cumbersome reformatting of the paths.

Also worth nothing that I set up specific NTFS denials on the folders I want to omit, but Robocopy somehow access them still via a mapped drive that is mapped with the account that is denied. If I try to browse with the GUI into those folders, I get denied, but robocopy is able to access it somehow. I REALLY don't understand that part.

Regardless, the real issue is that I can't pass the argument /XD "application data" to robocopy with Powershell. Maybe I should use something other than Start-Process?

I was trying this code first, but it has the same issue with spaces and nested quotes:
$options = @("/XD "application data"")
@cmdArgs = @("$source","$dest",$options)
robocopy @cmdArgs

I'm about ready to just use a looping batch file for my robocopy like the old days, but I feel like there MUST be a way with Powershell. Thanks if you can help me!

Comment: I might be okay doing "/XD application*" but some users could have actual folders that get omitted, like "applications for credit" or whatever.

Comment: I have to ask, why do you need to do this with Powershell if Robocopy on it's own accomplishes the task?